# Url won't redirect using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, prestashop

i have a issue on the website im working on, i have 2 urls, url1

```
https://www.fakeurl/fr/histoires-d-art/interview-peintre-anne-baudequin
```

and url2

```
https://www.fakeurl/fr/module/_edito/EditoContent?slug=interview-peintre-anne-baudequin
```

Both url display the same content but i want to redirect url2 to url1 using htaccess, the code i wrote in in htaccess is not working and i dont understand why. This is it

```
redirect 301 /fr/module/_edito/EditoContent?slug=interview-peintre-anne-baudequin https://www.fakeurl/fr/histoires-d-art/interview-peintre-anne-baudequin
```

Comment: you want to redirect just for this slug parameter ? `slug=interview-peintre-anne-baudequin`

Comment: @TarangP I mostly want to redirect because of the "module/_edito/EditoContent" part of the url but also because of the slug parameter yes

Comment: Try by giving full url
`RewriteRule  http://yourddomain.com/extra/param /http://yourdomain.com/other/url [R=301,L]`

Comment: @TarangP Not working :/

Answer (score 1):

The mod_alias `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only, not the question string, so the above does not match the requested URL.

You need to use mod_rewrite with an additional condition that matches against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable (or `THE_REQUEST`). However, you also need to be careful of redirect loops since I assume you are also using a front-controller (that internally rewrites URL1).

Try the following instead, at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
# Redirect URL2 to URL1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s/fr/module/_edito/EditoContent\?slug=interview-peintre-anne-baudequin\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /fr/histoires-d-art/interview-peintre-anne-baudequin [QSD,R=301,L]
```

`THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the request headers and does not change when the request is internally rewritten.

The `QSD` flag is necessary to remove the original query string from the redirect response.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

**UPDATE:** Fixed regex to backslash-escape the literal `?` and added slash prefix to the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string.

Comment: What you suggested didn't work unfortunately, but i looked a bit more into how htaccess worked, so i figured it out by myself, thanks for the time you took to help me tho :)

Comment: @TomVanEerdt Sorry, yes - there were a couple of errors in what I initially posted (now updated/corrected). I forgot to backslash-escape the literal `?` in the _CondPattern_ and the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ should start with a slash!

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out by myself, i had to change my code to this for it to work.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /fr/module/_edito/EditoContent\?slug=interview-peintre-anne-baudequin\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /fr/histoires-d-art/interview-peintre-anne-baudequin? [L,R=301]
```